# Cordova - sqlite plugin installed but echoTest function failed on Android Simulator on Browser

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Hybrid APP with Cordova and would like to use the cordova sqlite plugin to store some data on the Android device.

I have installed the plugin.

```
>cordova plugin ls

cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.0 "Diagnostic"
```

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage#readme), I wanted to run the echoTest function to verify the successful installation upon the deviceready event.

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function() {      
      console.log("Device is ready!");

      // test sqllite plugin
      window.sqlitePlugin.echoTest(function() {
        console.log('echoTest OK');
        alert('echoTest OK');
      });

   });
```

When I ran the "Simulate Android in browser" from VS Code, it threw the following error.

```
TypeError: errorcb is not a function
    at Object.ok [as success] (c:\Users\chena\CordovaApp\plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\www\SQLitePlugin.js:900:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/simulator/app-host.js:132:31)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:4:10860)
    at Socket.onevent (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:4:5790)
    at Socket.onpacket (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:4:5306)
    at Manager.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:4:9520)
    at Manager.Emitter.emit (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:4:10860)
    at Manager.ondecoded (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:3:31751)
    at Decoder.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:4:9520)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (http://localhost:8000/simulator/thirdparty/socket.io.js:3:3710)
```

It was noted this, along with all db.transaction calls, worked well on Android Emulator or an actual Android device.

Comment: The only apis you can use without building are located [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/plugin-apis).

Comment: This resource you pointed out also ended up navigating me to the documentation I was following.

Comment: So, if you're using the Developer App, you're aware it should be called the PhoneGap with Minimal Plugins Test App? And you're aware the PhoneGap Desktop App should be called the PhoneGap Test Server for the PhoneGap with Minimal Plugins Test App? The File Plugin can store data in your App without Building. Note that you should list all of the plugins you use in `config.xml` anyways, so when you build they will be there. PhoneGap out of the Box has all sorts of problems, by the way.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear that I am not using the PhoneGap build but the native Cordova.